# docker-maven-plugin(spotify) build the multiple modules

Tags: maven, spotify

My project has the following structure:

`pom.xml
  |
  x----common
  |      |
  |      x----pom.xml
  |
  x----sub
         |
         x----pom.xml`

`common` is the public module, generate the `common.jar`, and the `sub` module depends on it, so how to config the spotify plugin?

currently, the `pom.xml` in sub looks like:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
<artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>${docker.plugin.version}</version>
<configuration
    <imageName>${docker.image.prefix}/${project.build.finalName}</imageName>
    <dockerDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/docker</dockerDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <targetPath>/</targetPath>
            <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
            <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</configuration>
```

thanks for any help~

Answer (score 0):

solved it by `maven-antrun-plugin`